# Codeigniter Trying to get property 'gambar' of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i can't delete image file on folder when using unlink

it show me an error that said

> Trying to get property 'gambar' of non-object

here is my code

```
private function hapusGbr($id){
    $gambar = $this->db->get_where('artikel', array('id'=>$id))->row()->gambar;
    unlink("gambar/".$gambar);
}
```

Comment: what is `->gambar` after `->row()` ?? remove that part

Comment: calling a name of (gambar) field in my database. gambar means image in my language

Answer (score 1):

**Use as below**

```
private function hapusGbr($id){
    $gambar = $this->db->get_where('artikel', array('id'=>$id))->row();

    if($gambar){
      unlink("gambar/".$gambar->gambar);
    }

}
```

Comment: well thanks to this the error message has gone, but i still can't deleting image from my folder using unlink

Comment: see that $gambar->gambar is your image name or not, confirm that

Comment: no it's not, it is the name of database field. can you explain to me how to get a value of "gambar" field in my database. im struggling with it because i dont really understand how it works

Comment: just print_r the variable $gambar